# DnD elements cannot be made content editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing an wysiwyg, DnD (Drag and Drop), text editor in html5 and javascript.

I am making use of the new [html5sortable](https://github.com/voidberg/html5sortable) library. I have an issue that seems unaddressed.
I want to make some elements both DnD and content editable. Sorting plugin works and desired elements are sortable but the sortable class elements does not behave content editable.

What am I missing?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.sortable.js"></script>

    <style>
    li.sortable-placeholder {
        border: 1px dashed #CCC;
        background: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="sortable">
        <div contenteditable="true">Item 1</div>
        <div contenteditable="true">Item 2</div>
        <div contenteditable="true">Item 3</div>
        <div contenteditable="true">Item 4</div>
    </div>
    <div contenteditable="true">Item editable</div>

    <script>
    $('.sortable').sortable({

    }).bind('sortupdate', function(e, ui){
    });

    </script>

</body>
```

I try handles, but still it does not make content editable:

```
    <!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML5 Sortable jQuery Plugin</title>
  <link href="http://thomasf.github.io/solarized-css/solarized-light.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <style>
        header, section {
            display: block;
        }
        #features {
            margin: auto;
            width: 460px;
            font-size: 0.9em;
        }
        .connected, .sortable, .exclude, .handles {
            margin: auto;
            padding: 0;
            width: 310px;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        .sortable.grid {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .connected li, .sortable li, .exclude li, .handles li {
            list-style: none;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            background: #F6F6F6;
            font-family: "Tahoma";
            color: #1C94C4;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            height: 22px;
        }
        .handles span {
            cursor: move;
        }
        li.disabled {
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        .sortable.grid li {
            line-height: 80px;
            float: left;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        li.highlight {
            background: #FEE25F;
        }
        #connected {
            width: 440px;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .connected {
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
        }
        .connected.no2 {
            float: right;
        }
        li.sortable-placeholder {
            border: 1px dashed #CCC;
            background: none;
        }
    </style>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <h2>Sortable List With Handles</h2>
        <ul class="handles list">
            <li contenteditable="true"><span>::</span> Item 1</li>
            <li contenteditable="true"><span>::</span> Item 2</li>
            <li contenteditable="true"><span>::</span> Item 3</li>
            <li contenteditable="true"><span>::</span> Item 4</li>
            <li contenteditable="true"><span>::</span> Item 5</li>
            <li contenteditable="true"><span>::</span> Item 6</li>
        </ul>
    </section>

    <!-- <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.0/zepto.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/html.sortable.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.handles').sortable({
                handle: 'span'
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQueryUI used to have similar issue . For DND they disable text selection on element but there was a `handle` option that made it easy to work around. Likely same issue here. Look in source code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sample code on the [html5 sortable](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/voidberg/html5sortable/blob/master/examples/examples.html) website it appears the issue is with the [role] attribute.  If you remove that it will work, I guess that maybe the library adds that attribute ?

e.g. try running at the JavaScript console :

```
$("li").attr("contentEditable", "true");
```

Then - to get it to work :

```
$("li").removeAttr("role");
```

Note that the dragstart and selectionstart events are indistinguishable so you wont be able to select the editable text (it'll initiate a drag).

Comment: But I haven't had role attributes on list items as I have given the code above.

Comment: Can you confirm that by inspecting the elements using the browser dev tools ? Try creating a demo without the library, it seems to work OK for me.

Comment: yes you are right. the library adds this role attribute to the elements.

Comment: But removing this does not make it editable. Do you mean by your last line, no way to achieve this because those two events indistinguishable?

Comment: If you add contenteditable and remove role then it should work. You just can't select text using the mouse.

Comment: It doesn't. I am on Safari on my mac.

Comment: Hmmmm it works on Firefox, and on chrome. Maybe contenteditable and draggable just don't go together on safari.

Comment: On Safari drag and drop works but not content editable, on the other hand on Chrome drag and drop doesn't work but content editable works.

Comment: my results for this fiddle; on Safari DND not works and CE not works. On Chrome only CE works.clicking and dragging selects text.

Comment: well - i dunno what else to suggest.  It appears to select the text only if you try and drag it by making the drag gesture over the text, if you drag elsewhere it works.  Like i said in the answer the two gestures are very similar anyway, it's unusual to be able to edit something and drag it while it's editable, maybe turn dragging off while it's editable or something is all I can suggest.

Comment: Is that possible to have a div draggable containing the another div containing the text editable to distinguish the area of sensitivity to gestures. the left side of the outer div is sensitive to only draggable, yet the rest is sensitive to content editable since it overlaps with the inner div.